# Perl checking condition for folders created recursively

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I have created a simple script to create the folders recursively in /123/456. The script goes as follows:

```
$a='123';
$b='456';
$c = 'abc';
unless (-d $c){
    mkdir $c;
}
chdir("$a/$b/$c");


$d = 'def';
unless (-d $d){
    mkdir $d;
}
chdir ("$a/$b/$c/$d");

$e = 'ghi';
unless (-d $e){
    mkdir $e;
}
chdir ("$a/$b/$c/$d/$e");
chdir ("$a/$b);
```

Now, I need to check the flow of the directory is correct or not. Please can you suggest if I can insert another if condition to check it or die method in the above script. I am copying files in the above folders respectively.

I am a newbie to perl. So. correct me in case of mistake. Thank you.

Comment: why don't you simply use `File::Path`? It exports `mkpath()`, which is equivalent to `mkdir -p`

Comment: @mvp - Thank you for your quick response. mkpath() wants me to provide the whole list of the directory tree. I have it in terms of variables. That is why I choose this way. Any suggestions on how to make it better?

Comment: you can do this: `mkpath(join("/", $a, $b, $c, $d, $e));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code instead, which is like 10x simpler:

```
use File::Path qw(mkpath);

mkpath("123/456/abc/def/ghi")
    or die "Cannot create directory structure";
```

Comment: @mvp- '/' notation is affecting me as sometimes I need to use this script on a Windows platform..Any suggestions how to overcome it?

Comment: `abc\\def\\ghi` in windows

Comment: @deep Use slashes anyway, because they work just as well in Windows.

Comment: Windows supports `/` just fine. If you are really so inclined, use `catfile` or `catdir` exported by [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html), something like `$path = File::Spec->catfile(@directories, $filename);`